# SwiftUI conflict with rotation3DEffect animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

> code ref: https://github.com/amosgyamfi/swiftui-animation-library/blob/master/After%20WWDC2020/Parallax%203D/ios_3d_parallax.gif

When i change state horizontalAlignment and use it in VStack(alignment: horizontalAlignment), the content will move from left to center.

I want to toggle between center and leading with tap of button

### Current effect:

[image]

### Expect effect:

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var rotateIn3D = false
    @State private var horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment = .leading
    
    let weatherBg = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.white]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack { // Weather
                VStack(alignment: horizontalAlignment) {
                    Text("Wednesday")
                    
                    Text("18°")
                        .font(.system(size: 44))
                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
                    Text("Partly Cloudy")
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 20, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("H:21° L:12°")
                    
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(22)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                
            }.frame(width: 170, height: 170, alignment: .leading)
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotateIn3D ? 12 : -12), axis: (x: rotateIn3D ? 90 : -45, y: rotateIn3D ? -45 : -90, z: 0))
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
            .onAppear() {
                rotateIn3D.toggle()
            }
            Button(action: {
                horizontalAlignment = .center
            }, label: {
                Text("Change Horizontal Alignment to center")
            })
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.dark/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make animations per value of each state separated.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
  // ... other code

    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotateIn3D ? 12 : -12), axis: (x: rotateIn3D ? 90 : -45, y: rotateIn3D ? -45 : -90, z: 0))
    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), 
         value: rotateIn3D) // << here !!
    .animation(.default, value: horizontalAlignment)  // << here !!
    .onAppear() {
        rotateIn3D.toggle()
    }
```

Comment: @Asperi: For me works without ***.animation(.default, value: horizontalAlignment)*** for me it was unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Here: As you wished all in center

```
    import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var rotateIn3D = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack { 
                VStack {
                    Text("Wednesday")
                    
                    Text("18°")
                        .font(.system(size: 44))
                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
                    Text("Partly Cloudy")
                    Text("H:21° L:12°")
                    
                }
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(22)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                
            }.frame(width: 170, height: 170, alignment: .leading)
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotateIn3D ? 12 : -12), axis: (x: rotateIn3D ? 90 : -45, y: rotateIn3D ? -45 : -90, z: 0))
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
            .onAppear() {
                rotateIn3D.toggle()
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

**Update: Version 2.0.0**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rotateIn3D = false
    @State var alignmentToggle = false
    
    
    let weatherBg = RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.white]), center: .center, startRadius: 30, endRadius: 200)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        ZStack
        {
            
            
            VStack(alignment: alignmentToggle ? .leading : .center)
            {
                
                
                Text("Wednesday")
                Text("18°").font(.system(size: 44)).fontWeight(.thin)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
                Text("Partly Cloudy")
                Text("H:21° L:12°")
                
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 170, height: 170)
            .background(weatherBg)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(22)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.7), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 30)
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotateIn3D ? 12 : -12), axis: (x: rotateIn3D ? 90 : -45, y: rotateIn3D ? -45 : -90, z: 0))
            .animation( rotateIn3D ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2))
            .onAppear() { rotateIn3D.toggle() }
            
            VStack
            {
                Spacer()
                Button("alignment toggle"){
                    rotateIn3D.toggle()
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.1) {
                        alignmentToggle.toggle()
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.1) {
                            rotateIn3D.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
 
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: when i change state `horizontalAlignment` and use it in `VStack(alignment: horizontalAlignment)` , problem still exists

Comment: i want to dynamically change ui

Comment: I really do not understand you! you asked for center and I gave the Answer! Do you want toggle between center and leading with tap of button? Explain what you want plz.

Comment: Yes, i want to toggle between center and leading with tap of button